# Add/remove jQuery Validation rule based on Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, dynamic, rules

I'm having a problem changing a specific rule from jQuery Validation based on an Ajax Get request.

I have one form composed by one parent form and two child forms that are updated by  Jquery.post request. The two child forms, when submitted, updates a counter that is saved into their respectives hidden inputs, and the validation upon the condition that the counters needed to have at least 1 item registered for both worked fine...
until the rule get more complex.

Now, depending on the value of the items of the first child form saved, the "min" rule has to be activated or not.

Example: the items have code values between 200 and 500; if there's at least one item registered with a code above or equal 300 the "min" rule has to be applied, otherwise it's not needed. The problem is that it has to be resolved dynamically, because if the items that have code >= 300 are removed from first child form list, or if there's not any item with that code value and then one of them is saved, the validation rules have to be updated.

I´ve tried updating rule on the return of the $.post success function, it only add the rule, never remove it at all:

```
$.get('{url of the updating form}', function(data){
    if (data >=300) {
       $('#counter_form_child_2').rules('add', { min: 1 });
    } else {
       $('#counter_form_child_2').rules('remove'); //removes all rules for this input
    }
});
```

Tried to make a query that returns bool (true or false) searching if there's any item with code >=300 and putting it into another hidden field:

```
//Code inside the js function that returns the boolean value
$.get('{url of the updating form}', function(data) {
     $('#item_above_300').val(data); //puts value into hidden field
});

//Code inside form validation rules
$("#parentForm").validate({
   ignore: ':hidden:not(#counter_form_child1, #counter_form_child1),
   rules : {
      (...)
      counter_child_form1: { min: 1 },
      counter_child_form2: { 
         min: { param: 1,
           depends: function(element) {
               return $('#item_above_300').val() === 1;
           }
         }
       }
     }
});
```

I need some help, because I'm exausted of trying several alternatives and nothing works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the problem wasn't on the rules actually...
Testing the valid fields using showErrors, I could debug and found out that the hidden field was updating correctly and the error counted out:

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
   var submitted = true;
   if (submitted) {
      var summary = "Precisa corrigir os seguintes erros: <br/>";
      $.each(errorMap, function(name, value) { 
         summary += " * (" + name +  + value + "<br/>"; 
      });                   
      $("#msg_aviso").html(summary);
      submitted = false;
   }
   this.defaultShowErrors();
}
```

Then I found out that the problem was at the errorMessage displaying.
And ONLY at the counter_child_form2 message.
So, after researching at some questionings here at Stack Overflow I found that the solution was reset the DIV that displays that specific error message every submit form event. And... voilá, it worked!

```
$('#parentForm').click(function(){
    $("#counter_child_form2_error .error").html('');
    $("#parentForm").submit();
});
```